# TelephonyManager deprecated listen(),its function and classes

Tags: java, android, phone-state-listener, recorder

I am making an app for my project which records ongoing calls and transcribes them for people.
I am having issue with `PhoneStateListener()`, `onCallStateChanged()` and `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE`. These are all deprecated. Can anyone help me in running it or updating it?

```java
public class RecordingService extends Service {
    private MediaRecorder rec;
    private boolean recordstarted;
    private File  file;
    String path="/sdcard/alarms/";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS);
        rec = new MediaRecorder();
        rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        rec.setOutputFile(file.getAbsoluteFile()+"/"+"rec.3gp");
        rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        manager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
               // super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber){
                    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state && rec == null) {
                        rec.stop();
                        rec.reset();
                        rec.release();
                        recordstarted = false;
                        stopSelf();
                    } else if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                        try {
                            rec.prepare();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        rec.start();
                        recordstarted = true;
                    }
                }

        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to work and not to be deprecated. Can anyone provide me the updated code or a way to run it?